# Let P1 and P2 be path connected. Prove that P1 x P2 is path connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

So we know that separately they are both path connected.
That in the topological space X $\forall x,y \in X$  $\exists$ $f: I \rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. 
Given P1 and P2 are path connected.... ok not sure what now....

Comment: Hint: If two paths $f_1$ and $f_2$ are given, consider $(f_1, f_2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right),\left(y_{1},y_{2}\right)\in P_{1}\times P_{2}$.

If there are continous functions $f_{i}:\mathbb{I}\rightarrow P_{i}$
with $f_{i}\left(0\right)=x_{i}$ and $f_{i}\left(1\right)=y_{i}$
then $f:\mathbb{I}\rightarrow P_{1}\times P_{2}$ defined by $t\mapsto\left(f_{1}\left(t\right),f_{2}\left(t\right)\right)$
is continous and is a path from $\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)$ to $\left(y_{1},y_{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $(x_1,x_2), (y_1, y_2) \in X_1\times X_2$. Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are path connected, you have pathes $f_1:I\to X_1$ with $f_1(0)=x_1$, $f_1(1)=y_1$ and $f_2:I\to X_2$ with $f_2(0)=x_2$, $f_2(1)=y_2$. Use $f_1$ and $f_2$ to construct a map $f:I\to X_1\times X_2$ with $f(0)=(x_1, x_2)$ and $f(1)=(y_1, y_2)$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: In $\Bbb R^2$ you can get from $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ to $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ by going horizontally to $\langle x_1,y_0\rangle$ and then vertically to $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$. You’re using here the fact that $\Bbb R$ is path connected.